# Regular Expression find duplicate words

Tags: python, regex, duplicates

I have a list of words, where some are the same. I need to find these duplicates to replace them with an empty string. I don't have any problems with the replacement inside python, but with the regular expression I try to use.
This is an example of my list:

```
AC;AC MR;TA;AC MR;AC;AC MR;TA;SDA
```

The words are seperatet by a semicolon.

The expression I use is:

```
\b(\w+\s*\w+)\b;(?=.*\1)
```

I tried it without the spaces between the words like that:

```
AC;ACMR;TA;ACMR;AC;ACMR;TA;SDA
```

The result I get here, when I replace the matches with nothing is:

```
ACMR;TA;SDA
```

What I want as an result in the end is:

```
AC;ACMR;TA;SDA
```

You can see that there is no AC. He always matches the standalone AC and replaces it, when it comes before the ACMR. But these are different words and I need one of every word in my result.

Can someone help me with that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm doing this in ArcGIS Pro with a short python syntax. I'm new to python and RegEx and haven't found a better way yet. If you have a better solution you can tell me that :)

Comment: I don't write python, but in Java I would split the string using the delimiter so I have an array, then just iterate though to see if each index matches another index. Thats kinda what a programming language is for. Regex can do this Im sure, and there are some really good regex websites out there than can help. REGEX101 has a debugger that can be helpful. I suggest using an array and loop though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *This is getting much complicated than I expected, you should try a non-regex solution*

Try this regex:

```
(?:(?<=;)|(?<=^))([^;]+)(?=.*;\1(?=;|$));
```

- `(?:...)` non-capture group
- `(?<=;)|(?<=^)` lookbehinds, make sure the following word is followed by `;` or the beginning of the string
- `([^;]+)` anything that not made by `;`, and put it in group 1
- `(?=.*;\1(?=;|$))` lookahead, there's a duplicate of group 1 ahead followed by a `;` and a `;` or the end of the string after it
- `;` match the `;` after the word

Check the [results](https://regex101.com/r/wrlmBO/1/)

---

Using python:

```py
import re

text = 'AC;AC MR;TA;AC MR;AC;AC MR;TA;SDA'
result = re.sub(r'(?:(?<=;)|(?<=^))([^;]+)(?=.*;\1(?=;|$));', '', text)
print(result) # AC;AC MR;TA;SDA
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I already have the setup for the RegEx and not much time to try somethign different. It seems that your solution is working pretty good for my data, so I'll stay with that. Next time I try and use another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the order, one option might be using split and join and removing the spaces from the values.

```
s = "AC;AC MR;TA;AC MR;AC;AC MR;TA;SDA"
print(";".join([x.replace(' ', '') for x in dict.fromkeys(s.split(";"))]))
```

Output

```
AC;ACMR;TA;SDA
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/6lxKQt)

If you want to find the word(s) separated by spaces, you might use re.findall with a pattern to match 1+ word chars optionally repeated by 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ word chars `w+(?:\s+\w+)*`

```
import re
s = "AC;AC MR;TA;AC MR;AC;AC MR;TA#$@#$;SDA"
print(";".join([x.replace(' ', '') for x in dict.fromkeys(re.findall(r"\w+(?:\s+\w+)*", s))]))
```

Output

```
AC;ACMR;TA;SDA
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/9BHHrV)

Comment: Thanks. I already have the setup for the RegEx and not much time to try somethign different. So I'll stay with that and use the RegEx solution above. Next time I try and use a split and join.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression doesn't seem like the right tool to use here.

Alternatively, you could split the string by its separator, get the unique values and join them back together:

```
s = 'AC;AC MR;TA;AC MR;AC;AC MR;TA;SDA'
print(';'.join(set(s.split(';')))) # 'AC;TA;AC MR;SDA'
```

Although this still involves multiple steps, it might be easier to follow than a complex reg ex. Note that the order of words may not be preserved.

Comment: Thanks. I already have the setup for the RegEx and not much time to try somethign different. So I'll stay with that and use the RegEx solution above. Next time I try and use your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If no use RegEx, There is a solution:

```
data = "AC;ACMR;TA;ACMR;AC;ACMR;TA;SDA"
dataList = data.split(";");

seen = set()
duplicated = set()
for value in dataList:  
    if value not in seen:  
        seen.add(value)
    else:
        duplicated.add(value)

print(duplicated)
```

Result:

```
{'TA', 'ACMR', 'AC'}
```